# Mineração de texto com R (stringr)

Tags: string, r

Tenho um string de lenght 15 e quero remover os primeiros 70 charac. e os últimos 200 charac. de cada um.

Tentei o seguinte código para remover os começos e não deu certo:

```
 texto2009a <- texto2009 %>% map(str_sub(., 1, 72) <- " ")
```

Comment: Bem-vinda ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: 1) O que é que acontece quando o texto tem menos de 70 caracteres? 2) E menos de 200? 3) E, já agora, menos de 70 + 200?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A partir da resposta do @Giovani, escrevi uma pequena função para resolver o problema da diferença entre o que `str_sub` faz e o que a pergunta pede.

Da página `help("str_sub")`, secção `Details`:

> Details
>
> Substrings are inclusive - they include the characters at both start
>   and end positions. str_sub(string, 1, -1) will return the complete
>   substring, from the first character to the last.

Ora a pergunta pede (editado por mim)

> remover os primeiros `m` caracteres e os últimos `n` caracteres

É portanto preciso começar em `m + 1` e no fim será `n - 1`.

```
library(stringr)

str_sub_als <- function(s, primeiros = 70, ultimos = -200){
    str_sub(s, primeiros + 1, ultimos - 1)
}

x <- c("1234567890", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")

str_sub(x, 3, -4)
#[1] "34567"                 "cdefghijklmnopqrstuvw"

str_sub_als(x, 3, -4)
#[1] "456"                 "defghijklmnopqrstuv"
```

Answer (score 5):

Exemplo fictício, que talvez possa ser reproduzido para o seu caso:

```
x<-c('Bem-vinda ao Stack Overflow em Português')

library(stringr)

str_sub(x, 2, -10) # as aspas do texto também contam como strings. Por isso, adicione uma unidade a mais
#[1] "em-vinda ao Stack Overflow em "
```

Onde, `2` e `-10` são, respectivamente, as quantidades de caracteres iniciais e finais que deseja remover.